# Toggling a div that is not this parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a dropdown menu for my website, and am using jQuery slideToggle. I have it working for each individual category on the navigation (When navparent is clicked, navhild toggles), however when clicking other parents, the previous child div remains open. I would like to close other divs when the parent is clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.navparent a').click(function(){ 
$(this).parent().find('.navchild').slideToggle(90);
```

---

```
         <div class="navmobile">
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/source.png" alt="Parent" title="Parent" />
                        <br />Parent
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> <li><a href="#">Child</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/source.png" alt="Parent" title="Parent" />
                        <br /> Parent
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> <li><a href="#">Child</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Just call the slideToggle function of the element you want the close in other divs click();

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide all child divs when clicking on parent.

```
$('.navmobile').find('.navchild').hide()
```

Comment: This will temporarily hide the parent you want to have open. Creates a flicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line to just hide all `.navchild` elements, then the one for the click will open.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.navchild').hide();
       $('.navparent a').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find('.navchild').slideToggle(90);  
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         <div class="navmobile">
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/dcls_rebuild/themes/custom/dcls/images/mylib_color.png" alt="My Library" title="My Library" />
                        <br /> MY LIBRARY
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> {{ page.main_navigation }}<li><a href="#">testestsetsetestsetsetsetsetsetes</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/dcls_rebuild/themes/custom/dcls/images/mylib_color.png" alt="My Library" title="My Library" />
                        <br /> MY LIBRARY
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> {{ page.main_navigation }}<li><a href="#">testestsetsetestsetsetsetsetsetes</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>


        </div>
```

Or you can just set the `.navchild` element to be hidden by default in the CSS. (Generally a more efficient way to handle this).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.navparent a').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find('.navchild').slideToggle(90);  
    });
    });
```

```css
.navchild { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         <div class="navmobile">
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/dcls_rebuild/themes/custom/dcls/images/mylib_color.png" alt="My Library" title="My Library" />
                        <br /> MY LIBRARY
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> {{ page.main_navigation }}<li><a href="#">testestsetsetestsetsetsetsetsetes</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navparent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/dcls_rebuild/themes/custom/dcls/images/mylib_color.png" alt="My Library" title="My Library" />
                        <br /> MY LIBRARY
                    </a>
                    <div class="navchild">
                        <ul> {{ page.main_navigation }}<li><a href="#">testestsetsetestsetsetsetsetsetes</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>


        </div>
```

```
.navchild { display: none; }
```

Comment: This will temporarily hide the parent you want to have open. Creates a flicker.

Comment: @adam-beck that is *specifically* why I added the CSS option. There's no "flicker' if you just hide them with CSS.

Comment: But that also changes the desired look as they are now all "closed" by default.

Comment: @adam-beck uhmm.. and you know DCLS wants everything visible to start? Most looking for this functionally don't want that.

Comment: Didn't make any assumptions. Just took the code DCLS has. And the code  given has the elements open by default. Plus, your solution doesn't close all the `.navchild` on click. It would only do it the first time.

Comment: @adam-beck :) I'm *not* the one making assumptions. The question includes *no css*, there's no telling the visibility of elements. based on the *text* of the question, it seems clear they are desired to *opened* on the click (big clue to functionality there) and *close* non-clicked children... so....

Comment: Okay @adam-beck I'm going to assume you're just looking for an argument.. have a great day!

Comment: Still, my point that this doesn't close the other `.navchild` elements holds true. Don't know how I'm looking for an argument here.

Comment: "I would like to close other divs when the parent is clicked."

Comment: Add your **own answer** then @adam-beck No one is stopping you.

Comment: I would not like the child divs visible to start, sorry for neglecting to mention this.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @DCLS I believe my answer above addresses the issue then. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you click on a parentnode, have the jQuery hide all of the children nodes except the one toggled:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.navchild').slideToggle(90);

   $('.navparent a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // determine what div is open
      var $this = $(this).parent().find('div');
      // hide all divs except this one
      $(".navparent div").not($this).hide();

      // toggle selected div
      $this.slideToggle(90);

    });
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamthejonsmith/BGSyS/900/